# Java Mandelbrot Set Viewer

Tags: java, performance, swing, floating-point, fractals

I'm writing my own version of a Mandelbrot set generator, with pan and zoom functionality. (There's not yet a color overlay of sets generated with various beta values; the beta value is changed manually with a spinner.)

- Pan: drag left-click
- Zoom: roll mouse wheel

The main problem with this code is that after zooming in ~500 times, the generated shape will jump around on the canvas, rather than staying centered on the mouse cursor. I've tried debugging and the best idea I have is that this error is due to the limits of floating-point precision.

(As a self-taught Java programmer) I'm looking for suggestions regarding:

- How to zoom in indefinitely without losing precision
- Improving performance
- Class structure and overall code style
- Any other improvements

---

Mandelbrot.java:

```java
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Mandelbrot
{
    private int beta = 50;
    private volatile boolean abort = false;
    private volatile boolean generating = false;
    private volatile int genCount = 0;

    private Mandelbrot()
    {
        new GUI(this);
    }

    /**
     * @return Whether the given complex number diverges from the origin-centered
     * circle of radius 2 after {@code beta} number of tries.
     */
    private boolean diverges(double real, double complex)
    {
        ComplexNumber cn = new ComplexNumber(real, complex);
        ComplexNumber z = new ComplexNumber(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < beta; i++)
        {
            z.add(z.square(), cn);
            if(z.real*z.real + z.complex*z.complex > 4)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void generatePoints(Point2D.Double tl, Point2D.Double br, int[] pixels, int threadID)
    {
//      final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Point2D.Double start = GUI.wtc(tl);
        Point2D.Double end = GUI.wtc(br);
        double increment = (end.x - start.x)/(double)(GUI.SIZE - 1);

        for(double y = start.y, cy = 0; cy < GUI.SIZE; y += increment, cy++)
        {
            // Stop computing if a new zoom/pan is commanded
            if(abort)
            {
                abort = false;
                System.out.printf("(%d) Aborting at cy %d\n", genCount, (int)cy);
                break;
            }
            for(double cx = 0, x = start.x; cx < GUI.SIZE; x += increment, cx++)
            {
                if(x*x + y*y > 4)
                    continue;
                if(!diverges(x, y))
                    pixels[(int) (cy*GUI.SIZE + cx)] = 0xFF000000;
            }
        }

//      long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
//      System.out.printf("thread %d time: %.3fs\n", threadID, elapsedTime / 1000000000.0);
    }

    int[] generatePoints(Point2D.Double tl, Point2D.Double br)
    {
        System.out.printf("(%d) Generating on thread: %s\n",
                genCount, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int[] pixels = new int[GUI.SIZE*GUI.SIZE];

        generating = true;
        //TODO multithreaded Mandelbrot calculation
        generatePoints(tl, br, pixels, 0);
        generating = false;

        long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("(" + genCount++ + ") Done. Took %.3fs\n\n", elapsedTime / 1000000000.0);

        return pixels;
    }

    void abortProcessing()
    {
        if(generating)
        {
            abort = true;
        }
    }

    void setBeta(int beta)
    {
        this.beta = beta;
    }

    int getBeta()
    {
        return beta;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Mandelbrot();
    }
}
```

GUI.java:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
final class GUI
{
    public static final int SIZE = 992; // Must be divisible by 4
    public static final double ZOOM_FACTOR = 1.1;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(SIZE, SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private Canvas canvas;

    GUI(Mandelbrot man)
    {
        canvas = new Canvas(man);
        refresh(man);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MandelBrot Set Viewer");
        frame.setContentPane(setupPanel(man));
        frame.pack();
//      frame.setLocation(5456, 5);
//      frame.setLocation(4200, 975);
//      frame.setLocation(4200, 5);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * Converts from window coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.
     */
    public static Point2D.Double wtc(Point2D.Double window)
    {
        return new Point2D.Double((window.x * 4 / (double)GUI.SIZE) - 2,
                (window.y * 4 / (double)GUI.SIZE) - 2 );
    }

    private JPanel setupPanel(final Mandelbrot man)
    {
        SpinnerModel betaModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(man.getBeta(), 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
        JSpinner betaSpinner = new JSpinner(betaModel);
        betaSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                man.setBeta((int)((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue());
                refresh(man);
            }
        });
        JLabel betaLabel = new JLabel("Beta value:");
        JPanel betaPanel = new JPanel();
        betaPanel.add(betaLabel);
        betaPanel.add(betaSpinner);

        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                canvas.reset();
            }
        });
        JPanel resetPanel = new JPanel();
        resetPanel.add(resetButton);

        JPanel sidePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        sidePanel.add(betaPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        sidePanel.add(resetPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(sidePanel);
        mainPanel.add(canvas);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    void refresh(Mandelbrot man)
    {
        //TODO use a Thread pool rather than creating a new Thread for each pan/zoom
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // Calculate Mandelbrot shape in the current viewing area
                image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                        man.generatePoints(canvas.tlClip, canvas.brClip));
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private final class Canvas extends JPanel
    {
        final Point2D.Double tl = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);
        final Point2D.Double br = new Point2D.Double(SIZE, SIZE);
        // Point in Cartesian space at the top left of the viewing window
        volatile Point2D.Double tlClip = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);
        // Point in Cartesian space at the bottom right of the viewing window
        volatile Point2D.Double brClip = new Point2D.Double(SIZE, SIZE);
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        Ellipse2D.Double backgroundCircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        int prevX, prevY;
        double scale = 1;

        Canvas(Mandelbrot man)
        {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    // For debugging
                    System.out.println("tlClip: " + tlClip);
                    System.out.println("brClip: " + brClip);
                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    prevX = e.getX();
                    prevY = e.getY();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    pan(man, e);
                }
            });
            addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
                {
                    zoom(man, e);
                }
            });
        }

        private void pan(Mandelbrot man, MouseEvent e)
        {
            man.abortProcessing(); // Stop processing the previous request--we have a new one

            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            double translateX = (x - prevX)/scale;
            double translateY = (y - prevY)/scale;
            transform.translate(translateX, translateY);

            updateClip();
            refresh(man);

            prevX = x;
            prevY = y;
        }

        private void zoom(Mandelbrot man, MouseWheelEvent e)
        {
            man.abortProcessing(); // Stop processing the previous request--we have a new one

            int rotation = e.getWheelRotation();
            Point2D p1 = e.getPoint();
            Point2D p2 = null;
            try
            {
                p2 = transform.inverseTransform(p1, null);
            }
            catch(NoninvertibleTransformException ex)
            {
                // Should not happen
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            transform.setToIdentity();
            scale = (rotation < 0) ? scale * ZOOM_FACTOR : scale / ZOOM_FACTOR;
            transform.translate(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
            transform.scale(scale, scale);
            transform.translate(-p2.getX(), -p2.getY());

            updateClip();
            refresh(man);
        }

        private void updateClip()
        {
            try
            {
                AffineTransform inv = transform.createInverse();
                inv.transform(tl, tlClip);
                inv.transform(br, brClip);
            }
            catch(NoninvertibleTransformException nte)
            {
                nte.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void reset()
        {
            transform.setToIdentity();
            scale = 1;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
//          final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_SPEED);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_SPEED);

            g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2d.fill(transform.createTransformedShape(backgroundCircle));

            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

//          long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
//          System.out.printf("painting time: %.3fs\n\n", elapsedTime / 1000000000.0);
        }
    }
}
```

ComplexNumber.java:

```java
package mandelbrot;

public class ComplexNumber
{
    public double real, complex;

    public ComplexNumber(double real, double complex)
    {
        this.real = real;
        this.complex = complex;
    }

    public ComplexNumber(double real)
    {
        this.real = real;
        complex = 0;
    }

    public void add(ComplexNumber cn1, ComplexNumber cn2)
    {
        real = cn1.real + cn2.real;
        complex = cn1.complex + cn2.complex;
    }

    public ComplexNumber square()
    {
//      double f = real * real;
//      double o = real * complex;
//      double i = real * complex;
//      double l = -(complex * complex);
        double realTemp = real;
        real = real * real - complex * complex;
        complex = realTemp * complex * 2;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return real + " + " + complex + "i";
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `void generatePoints` method, you are repeatedly calculating `y*y` inside the inner loop.  Try precalculating it before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great project to do. [I did a similar project in Swing](https://github.com/carcigenicate/mandelbrot/tree/master/src/mandelbrot); except using Clojure's Seesaw wrapper library. You can add many interesting add-on panels to it. My favorite panels that I came up with were a panel that lets the user decide how they want things colored, and one that allowed multiple images to be saved to disk in parallel. It was a great lesson in handling complex async processes. They're worth considering trying.

Anyways, onto some suggestions:

`diverges` can be made *much* more interesting if you allow it to return the `i` value that it fails at. This allows you to color your pixels based on the returned value of `i`, which adds a whole new dimension to what you can produce. [This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1asITJjqs-L7Iw7EeKFn6JiLYgbokGxlM) is my favorite image that I've ever produced (linking externally because it's 80 MB large; it's just my Google Drive. It's safe I swear!). Here's a *tiny* sample of it:

[image: Colored Mandelbrot Sample]

I'd change it to something like:

```
private int divergesAt(double real, double complex)
{
    ComplexNumber cn = new ComplexNumber(real, complex);
    ComplexNumber z = new ComplexNumber(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < beta; i++)
    {
        z.add(z.square(), cn);

        if(z.real*z.real + z.complex*z.complex > 4) { // Don't neglect braces!
            return i;
        }
    }

    return beta;
}
```

Then when you want to decide what color to make that pixel, do something like:

```
int iters = divergesAt(x, y);

// java.awt.Color
Color pixelColor = new Color(wrap(x * iters), wrap(y * iters), wrap((x + y) * iters);
```

Where `wrap` is some function that wraps the value to ensure that it's always between 0 and 255.

You can create much more complicated "equations" as well though. [Here](https://github.com/carcigenicate/mandelbrot/blob/master/src/mandelbrot/coloring.clj) are some example equations that I used (in Clojure; although you should be able to figure out what's going on). `wr` is a `wrap` shortcut, `co` is a `Color` constructor shortcut, `x` and `y` are the pixel coordinates, and `n` is the number of iterations that pixel failed at. Play around with it. I spent days just trying out different coloring methods.

---

On top of that, I have a couple comments regarding your `diverages` function:

- I would use far more whitespace, like how I showed in my example. Cramming everything together doesn't lend itself to readability.
- It's very confusing to have `ComplexNumber` as a mutable class. It's a number. Numbers are immutable. Ideally, the class methods should all return new `ComplexNumbers` instead of mutating themselves. This has the potential to be expensive; especially in a language like Java that doesn't lend itself to dealing with immutability. It will make your code make more sense though, and prevent bugs from popping up caused by background mutation.
- Don't be tempted to neglect braces just because they aren't necessary! Many odd bugs have occurred because we told ourselves "I'll definitely remember to add braces if I refactor this later". Limit your ability to cause future problems for yourself.

---

On your question about precision, the only way I found around that was to use `BigDecimal`; but this creates *massive* performance problems. I found using doubles actually lets you zoom in pretty far before stuff starts getting weird. I actually found my iteration limits (like your `beta` here) to be larger deciding factors in how the final image looks. Anything less than 200 for the limit causes noticeable missed details to start popping up.

Comment: Great feedback; thank you. I'll have a look at the links you provided. Will upvote as soon as I have >=15 rep!

Comment: I'm still hoping for a satisfying solution to the precision problem... I wonder how the _deep_ fractal zooms on Youtube were generated.

Comment: @PullNointer Likely using an arbitrary precision class like `BigDecimal` like I mentioned. They likely pre-computed everything before recording the zoom, so performance wasn't an issue. Or at least I always assumed that's how it was done.